# Postman response body variable is an ip address

Tags: postman

My response body returns this:

```
    "ServerList": {
        "192.168.88.128": {
            "encryption": "None",
            "host": "192.168.88.128"
        }
```

I'm trying to test for encryption using this:

```
const response = pm.response.json();

pm.test("Server Encryption Check", function () {
    pm.expect(response.ServerList.192.168.88.128.encryption).to.eql("None");
});
```

Can't seem to find a way to be able to have that ip in the test without a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference the property as an indexer:

```
response.ServerList["192.168.88.128"].encryption
```